# Can't boot Mac OSX 10.9 Virtual Machine (Virtual Box)

Tags: osx, virtualbox

Whenever I try to run the virtual machine this error comes up:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Mavericks.
>
> UUID {d2b7e883-8f73-41fc-9fde-11bc09a1a548} of the medium
>   '/home/username/VirtualBox VMs/Mavericks/Mavericks.vdi' does not match
>   the value {2ef03316-8e5e-44d8-b61e-b55ca5276cf3} stored in the media
>   registry ('/home/username/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml').
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: MediumWrap
>   Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}

My host machine is running Linux mint 17.2 and I am using the Niresh 'distro/pirated' 'version' of Mac OSX 10.9 (which i got from [this guide here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nod7cpxzxLc))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did ya try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074878/virtual-box-uuid-07c3-does-not-match-the-value-2c1b-stored-in-th

It seems to be a similar problem.